# how to replace a placeholder in a string?

Tags: php

Not very sure how to word this question but I'll give an example.

```
$string = 'Hey, $name. How are you?';
```

When I post this string, `$name` doesn't change. How can I make it so I can put something like `+name+` so it changes to the name. I've tried seaching for it but I don't know what to search for so I don't have any luck. It's probably really simple but i'm just blanking out.
Thanks

Comment: Basic PHP syntax: http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php

Answer (score 31, accepted):

You can use place-holders and [`str_replace`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-replace.php). Or use PHP's built-in [`sprintf`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.sprintf.php) and use `%s`. (And as of v4.0.6 you can swap the ordering of arguments if you'd like).

```
$name = 'Alica';

// sprintf method:
$format = 'Hello, %s!';
echo sprintf($format, $name); // Hello, Alica!

// replace method:
$format = "Hello, {NAME}!";
echo str_replace("{NAME}", $name, $format);
```

*And, for anyone wondering, I understood that is trouble templating a string, not PHP's integrated concatenation/parsing. I just assume keep this answer up though as I'm still not 100% sure this OP's intent*

Comment: thats what I was looking for, str_replace(); Thanks. I couldn't for the life of me figure it out.

Comment: @Alica: Not a problem. And if this answer was helpful, make sure to accept it (as with the other questions you've asked. Approving previous answers not only gives the person credit, but makes it a resource for future visitors, and makes others want to help you more).

Comment: `And as of v4.0.6...`  I hope you're not mentioning that because you think people are using something lower than PHP 4 ;)

Comment: @Tim: You never know. I _hope_ not, but some people like to hold on that antiquated stuff....

Answer (score 23):

I've always been a fan of `strtr`.

```
$ php -r 'echo strtr("Hi @name. The weather is @weather.", ["@name" => "Nick", "@weather" => "Sunny"]);'
Hi Nick. The weather is Sunny.
```

The other advantage to this is you can define different placeholder prefix types. This is how Drupal does it; `@` indicates a string to be escaped as safe to output to a web page (to avoid injection attacks). The [format_string](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes%21bootstrap.inc/function/format_string/7.x) command loops over your parameters (such as `@name` and `@weather`) and if the first character is an `@`, then it uses `check_plain` on the value.

Comment: This is a good answer because it also avoids some pitfalls that str_replace encounters: http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtr.php#117169

Answer (score 10):

You should be wrapping the string in double quotes (`"`) if you want variables to be expanded:

```
$name = "Alica";
$string = "Hey, $name. How are you?"; // Hey, Alica. How are you?
```

[See the documentation](http://php.net/manual/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.parsing).

Comment: Clean and simple, great.

Answer (score 2):

A third solution, no better or worse than the aforementioned, is concatenation:

`echo 'Hello '. $name .'!!!';`

Comment: It is ok unless you have to support translations where position of the placeholder changes with each language

Answer (score 0):

Another way to achieve this is to use [msgfmt_format_message](https://www.php.net/manual/fr/messageformatter.formatmessage.php)

You *must have the `intl` extension enabled*. Profile of the method is:

```php
msgfmt_format_message(string $locale, string $pattern, array $values): string|false`
```

For example:

```php
$name = "Alica";
$string = msgfmt_format_message('en_US', 'Hey, {0}. How are you?', array($name));
```

Would return: `Hey, Alica. How are you?`