# How to replace placeholders with actual values?

Tags: php

I need a function that replace every variable_name inside '{}' with the correct variable. 
Something like this:

```
$data["name"] = "Johnny";
$data["age"] = "20";

$string = "Hello my name is {name} and I'm {age} years old.";

$output = replace($string, $data);
echo $output;

//outputs: Hello my name is Johnny and I'm 20 years old.
```

I know there are framework/engines for this, but I don't want to have to install a bunch of files just for this.

Answer (score 11):

You can do this most easily with the `/e` modifier of `preg_replace`:

```
$data["name"] = "Johnny";
$data["age"] = "20";

$string = "Hello my name is {name} and I'm {age} years old.";

echo preg_replace('/{(\w+)}/e', '$data["\\1"]', $string);
```

**[See it in action](http://www.ideone.com/nuWDQ)**.

You might want to customize the pattern that matches the replacement strings (which here is `{\w+}`: one or more alphanumeric characters or underscores between curly brackets). Putting it into a function is trivial.

Comment: Nice solution, +1. Though I'd use `[^\}]+` instead of `\w`

Answer (score 2):

Here you go:

```
$data["name"] = "Johnny";
$data["age"] = "20";

$string = "Hello my name is {name} and I'm {age} years old.";

foreach ($data as $key => $value) {
$string = str_replace("{".$key."}", $value, $string);
}

echo $string;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$string = "Hello my name is {$data["name"]} and I'm {$data["age"]} years old.";
```

will do just what you want. If it is not suitable for you, try something like loop with the regex, like this

```
for ($data as $key=>$value){
    $string = preg_replace("\{$key\}", $value, $string);
}
```

Not tested, you might want to consult with documentation.

Comment: Any particular reason to use `preg_replace` instead of `str_replace` here?

Answer (score 0):

You can try out [`vsprintf`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.vsprintf.php) it has slightly different syntax

```
$string = 'hello my name is %s and I am %d years old';

$params = array('John', 29);

var_dump(vsprintf($string, $params));
//string(43) "hello my name is John and I am 29 years old"
```

Answer (score 0):

I've always been a fan of `strtr`.

```
$ php -r 'echo strtr("Hi @name. The weather is @weather.", ["@name" => "Nick", "@weather" => "Sunny"]);'
Hi Nick. The weather is Sunny.
```

The other advantage to this is you can define different placeholder prefix types. This is how Drupal does it; `@` indicates a string to be escaped as safe to output to a web page (to avoid injection attacks). The [format_string](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes%21bootstrap.inc/function/format_string/7.x) command loops over your parameters (such as `@name` and `@weather`) and if the first character is an `@`, then it uses `check_plain` on the value.

Also answered here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/36781566/224707